# MySQL How do I partially order a result set?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

If I have a set of results as which for example when visualised looks like [*status* | *date*] :

```
[1|2012/01/06],[2|2011/04/23],[3|2012/02/12],[1|2012/11/26],[2|2012/10/13],[3|2010/03/01],[3|2010/06/27]
```

How would I order the results so the rows with a **status of 1 have priority** over status' of 2 & 3 AND then order those 'split' results by the date?

If I order the status by ASC then I end up with:

```
[1|2012/01/06],[1|2012/11/26],[2|2011/04/23],[2|2012/10/13],[3|2012/02/12],[3|2010/03/01],[3|2010/06/27]
```

This separates the status' 2 & 3.
I want a result set which is like the following:

```
[1|2012/01/06],[1|2012/11/26],[3|2012/02/12],[3|2010/03/01],[2|2011/04/23],[3|2010/06/27],[2|2012/10/13]
```

tl;dr I want to order my results by either status of 1 or status > than 1. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following -

```
ORDER BY IF(status = 1, 1, 2) ASC, date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do 2 queries for this since you are asking for 2 things. Meaning: You ask for status=1 and you ask for everything except 1 ordered.

Those are 2 separate questions so why keep them in one query? It creates much more complexity in your query. MySQL is very fast at simple queries. This also allows clear model functions like for example:

```
 $Model->getByStatus(1)
 $Model->getByStatus(array(2,3))
```

Even more you could also create separate functions for them like:

```
 $Model->getPriorityTickets()
 $Model->getNonPriorityTickets()
```

Which creates an even more readable option which actually describes the business and does not needs the controller to know anything about the status id's. For example you could ass in getPriorityTickets another way of defining which records have priority by say: id=1 OR latest_modified > 2 days ago

Comment: The exact reason for this is because the data retrieved is selected using a WHERE column IN (id,id,id,id,id). I guess I could still split it into two queries but I wanted to refrain from that.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more or maybe add a code sample about the conditions not mentioned in your question?

Comment: There will be no benefit to splitting into two queries unless the filtered result set is very large.

Comment: Sure, I am using Sphinxsearch to search a large table and return a specific set of matches (ids). When displaying the results to the user the specified preference for a particular set of users is that those matches with the status of 1 have priority over status' of 2 + 3 along with the date column ordered. I have absolutely no idea if its possible to do it into one query. Forgot to mention I do some tinkering/modifications between sphinx and MySQL. The MySQL part of the process is retrieving additional information from the returned ids